# Solving differential equation with three variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve a simple differential equation with three variables to model dress state of atom with three energy level.

\begin{align}
    a_1'[t] &= \Omega_1 e^{i \Delta_1 t} *b[t]\\
    a_2'[t] &= \Omega_2 e^{i \Delta_2 t} *b[t]\\
    b'[t] &= \Omega_1 e^{-i \Delta_1 t} *a_1[t]+\Omega_2 e^{-i \Delta_2 t} *a_2[t]
\end{align}

where $\Omega_1$ ,$\Omega_2$, $\Delta_1$,$\Delta_2$ are just some constant. Initial conditions are followed,

\begin{align}
    a_1[0] &= 0\\
    a_2[0] &= 0\\
    b[0] &= 1 
\end{align}

I can assume that solution is 
\begin{align}
b[t] = K e^{-i\lambda t}
\end{align}

By integrating $a_1' [t]$ and $a_2' [t]$ and substitute in $b'[t]$, I got the solution such as

\begin{align}
\text{$\Delta $1} \text{$\Delta $2} \lambda +\text{$\Delta $1} \lambda ^2+\text{$\Delta $1} \text{$\Omega $2}^2+\text{$\Delta $2} \lambda ^2+\text{$\Delta $2} \text{$\Omega $1}^2+\lambda ^3
+\lambda  \text{$\Omega $1}^2+
\lambda  \text{$\Omega $2}^2=0
\end{align}

So I get three solutions, so my equation b[t] becomes

\begin{align}
b[t] = K1 e^{-i\lambda_1 t}+K2 e^{-i\lambda_2 t}+K3 e^{-i\lambda_3 t}
\end{align}

First by integrating a1 and a2, we got
\begin{align}
a_1[t]=\int \Omega_1 e^{i \Delta_1 t} *b[t]=-i \text{$\Omega $1} \left(\frac{\text{k1} e^{i t (\text{$\Delta $1}-\text{$\lambda $1})}}{\text{$\Delta $1}-\text{$\lambda $1}}+\frac{\text{k2} e^{i t (\text{$\Delta $1}-\text{$\lambda $2})}}{\text{$\Delta $1}-\text{$\lambda $2}}+\frac{\text{k3} e^{i t (\text{$\Delta $1}-\text{$\lambda $3})}}{\text{$\Delta $1}-\text{$\lambda $3}}\right)+C1\\
a_2[t]=\int \Omega_2 e^{i \Delta_2 t} *b[t]=-i \text{$\Omega $2} \left(\frac{\text{k1} e^{i t (\text{$\Delta $2}-\text{$\lambda $1})}}{\text{$\Delta $2}-\text{$\lambda $1}}+\frac{\text{k2} e^{i t (\text{$\Delta $2}-\text{$\lambda $2})}}{\text{$\Delta $2}-\text{$\lambda $2}}+\frac{\text{k3} e^{i t (\text{$\Delta $2}-\text{$\lambda $3})}}{\text{$\Delta $2}-\text{$\lambda $3}}\right)+C2
\end{align}

Using the initial condition of $a_1$ and $a_2$, I can get C1 and C2

\begin{align}
\text{C1}\to \frac{i \text{k1} \text{$\Omega $1}}{\text{$\Delta $1}-\text{$\lambda $1}}+\frac{i \text{k2} \text{$\Omega $1}}{\text{$\Delta $1}-\text{$\lambda $2}}+\frac{i \text{k3} \text{$\Omega $1}}{\text{$\Delta $1}-\text{$\lambda $3}}\\
\text{C2}\to \frac{i \text{k1} \text{$\Omega $2}}{\text{$\Delta $2}-\text{$\lambda $1}}+\frac{i \text{k2} \text{$\Omega $2}}{\text{$\Delta $2}-\text{$\lambda $2}}+\frac{i \text{k3} \text{$\Omega $2}}{\text{$\Delta $2}-\text{$\lambda $3}}
\end{align}

Now I try to solve K1, K2, and K3.

Using the b'[t] equation with initial condition, I got
\begin{align}
\text{k1} \text{$\lambda $1}+\text{k2} \text{$\lambda $2}+\text{k3} \text{$\lambda $3}=0
\end{align}

Then from the initical condition of b[t], I got
\begin{align}
k1 + k2 + k3 = 1
\end{align}

But I cannot find one more equation to find K1, K2, and K3. I already use $a_1$ and $a_2$ for finding constant C1 and C2. Do you have any recommendation which way I should go?

Comment: Use the normalisation condition on the state, that is the third equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your method.

Nevertheless, the calculus is too long to be edited. I give up !

There is a slight discrepancy about the equation for $\lambda$. I got :
$$\lambda+\frac{\Omega_1^2}{\lambda-\Delta_1}+\frac{\Omega_2^2}{\lambda-\Delta_2}=0$$
$$\lambda^3-(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)\lambda^2+(\Omega_1^2+\Omega_2^2+\Delta_1\Delta_2)\lambda-(\Omega_1^2\Delta_2+\Omega_2^2\Delta_1)=0$$
A mistake is possible. In fact, this isn't the key point.

Insofar the three $\lambda$ are correct, the exponentials in $b(t)$ are determined. It is expected to determine the coefficients $k_1\:,\:k_2\:,\:k_3$ from the three boundary conditions.

In fact two boundary conditions : $a_1(0)=0$ and $a_2(0)=0$ are not independent : the same equation $k_1\lambda_1+k_2\lambda_2+k_2\lambda_2=0$ is sufficient to make both satisfied.

So, together with the condition $b(0)=1\quad\to\quad k_1+k_2+k_3=1$ , all specified conditions are satisfied. This means that the solution of the problem is not unique. This isn't an exceptional case. One encounter such situations when the boundary conditions are insufficient or not independent.

I think that one must not loose time in searching a "missing" relationship. If the problem must have a unique solution, one have to search for an additional boundary condition missing in the present wording of the problem.